# Drop-down is not working properly in IE11?

Tags: java, javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

In my page there is a select box drop down. The select box drop down is getting displayed properly in IE8. But in IE11, if I am selecting any option apart from the first one, the whole select box option is getting moved up in the page.
In IE11, if option 2 is selected, then the select options is getting moved up. But in IE8, if option 2 is selected, then the select options is getting displayed properly.
Please let me know the fix so that the select options are displayed in the same manner as in IE8.

Mentioned the select tag code for your reference:

```
 <select name="<%=AddPromisesControl.MODE%><%=i%>"
            style="font-face: Arial; font-size: 8pt" 
            <%=isError ? "style='background-Color:yellow';"
                       :"style='background-Color:white';"%> >

        <% 
            l1=ModeCodeHome.singleton().findAll();
            options = l1.iterator();
            while (options.hasNext()) {
                Code value = (Code)options.next();
                String select = value.equals(promise.getMode()) ? "selected" : "";
        %>
        <option value="<%=value.getCode()%>" <%=select%>><%=value.getCode()%></option>
        <%
            } 
        %>         
</select>
```

Comment: Please don't dump code in a comment, edit your question. The problem you are having is very likely not specific to the selection box, it sounds more like a regular HTML/CSS problem that is related to the layout of your page. The snippet you post is of little help and I doubt this will have anything to do with Java.

Comment: I strong suggest you to write your logic involving method calls and iterators in a servlet, put the final data in request scope and use expression language (EL) and custom tags to print your values in HTML. Scriplets are a very very old way of writing JSPs and they're a maintenance hell. Also I suggest you to define styles in the top or in an external stylesheet and use those classes based on your if conditions rather than writing inline styles like yours :)

Comment: TQVM Frnds Gimby, Arkantos & user4749485
I really happy to received ideas from you guys thanks for your info, let me try in your ways.